# material ui Tooltip distance from the anchor

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, material-ui

Is there a clear/easy way to control Tooltip's distance from the anchor element? The default positioning does not fit well for my case, the tooltip is too close to the anchor. I have checked all the props of it and `PopperProps` no visible option to do that.

The GitHub issue about the same problem: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/19848.

Comment: have you tried overriding the margin like in this custom examples? https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/#customized-tooltips

Comment: Overriding the margin doesn't do anything :(

Comment: Any new solution ?

Answer (score 34):

With Material UI v5, it can be done like this:

```
<Tooltip
  PopperProps={{
    modifiers: [
      {
        name: "offset",
        options: {
          offset: [50, 0],
        },
      },
    ],
  }}
>
```

Comment: Work perfect in V5 , thanks

Comment: I wanted it even closer, used this - `sx={{ "& .MuiTooltip-tooltip": { marginBottom: "8px !important" } }}`

Comment: If you bring it too close with offset, the marginBottom would overlap with the element and prevent from clicking on it, so better use first @chrismarx style and after that move it accordingly with offset

Answer (score 24):

You can customize the tooltip's margin using [withStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api).

In my case (**Material-UI 3**), the tooltip was too far away from the anchor.
Here is what I needed :

```
const StyledTooltip = withStyles({
  tooltipPlacementTop: {
    margin: "4px 0",
  },
})(Tooltip);
```

I targeted `tooltipPlacementTop` because it was the rule name when using the `placement="top"` prop.
You can find the adequate rule names in the [Tooltip API documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/#css).

Last tip: I used the `PopperProps={{ keepMounted: true }}` prop to see in my navigator's inspector what CSS was applied to the tooltip.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

Follow up with Hugo's suggestion, since the tooltip position is absolute, instead of changing the *margin* I changed the anchor position by adjusting the properties *right* and *top* like so:

```
const StyledTooltip = withStyles({
  tooltipPlacementTop: {
    right: "1px",
    top: "8px",
  },
})(Tooltip);
```

It works as I expected. You can use *left* or right to adjust the tooltip horizontal position accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

In Material-UI v4, you can add `margin` via `style` prop in the `PopperProps`.

```
<Tooltip
  placement="bottom"
  title="hello"
  PopperProps={{ style: { marginTop: -12 } }}
>
  <div>Some text</div>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using material ui styled to adjust my tooltip properties. I used the normal theme which is available in the MUI documentation.

```
const LightTooltip = styled(({ className, ...props }) => (
<Tooltip {...props} classes={{ popper: className }} />))(({ theme }) => ({
[`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[1],
    fontSize: 11
},}));
```

I tried to adjust the position property with Mui styled, but it wasn't working.
I fixed it with my external style sheet.

```
.MuiTooltip-popper {
inset: -25px auto 0px auto;}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to change the distance between anchor and tooltip. In my case I need to decrease default margin from 14px to 2 px.
Here is my code.

```
MuiTooltip: {
  styleOverrides: {
    tooltip: ({ ownerState, theme }) => {
      return ({
        '&.MuiTooltip-tooltip': {
          '&.MuiTooltip-tooltipPlacementBottom': {
            marginTop: '2px',
          },
          '&.MuiTooltip-tooltipPlacementTop': {
            marginBottom: '2px',
          },
          '&.MuiTooltip-tooltipPlacementLeft': {
            marginRight: '2px',
          },
          '&.MuiTooltip-tooltipPlacementRight': {
            marginLeft: '2px',
          },
        },
      });
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Material-UI 4.x** version and changed tooltip distance from the anchor using following style

```
const HtmlTooltip = withStyles(theme => ({
    arrow: {
        '&::before': {
            color: 'white'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: '#f5f5f9',
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[8],
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
        fontSize: 14,
        maxWidth: 800,
        padding: 0,
    },
    tooltipPlacementTop: { // this part will change the distance
        margin: '4px 0', 
    },
}))(Tooltip)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set it through the style prop

```
<Tooltip style={{ padding: '4px 0'}} > {children} </Tooltip>
```